# Creating chat activity with recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

For my first non-trivial Android app, I am making an app that involves chat rooms. I am using the chat room activity to teach myself recyclerView, which isn't covered as extensively as the somewhat antiquated listView in reference materials. I think I'm close to having a working recyclerView and adapter that I built trying to translate some of the elements of a listView into a recyclerView, but I am having trouble actually making the messages appear in the recyclerView.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my chat room activity:

```
public class ChatRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Chat Room Activity";

private String mRoomID;
private String mRoomName;
private String mDisplayName;
private ArrayList<String> mUsernames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mMessages = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private EditText mInputText;
private ImageButton mSendButton;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ChatRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);

    Log.d(TAG," onCreate: started.");

    //  identifies views


    mInputText = findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
    mSendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    //gets user display name from current user and gets Firebase reference

    setupDisplayName();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    // gets Google Place ID from shared preferences

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PLACE_PREFS, 0);
    mRoomID = preferences.getString(PLACE_ID_KEY, null);
    mRoomName = preferences.getString(PLACE_NAME_KEY, null);

    Toast.makeText(this, mRoomID + mRoomName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //  Creates listener to send the message when the "enter" button is pressed

    mInputText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            sendMessage();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Adds an OnClickListener to the sendButton to send a message

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });

}

private void setupDisplayName() {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mDisplayName = user.getDisplayName();
}

private void sendMessage() {

    //  Grabs the text the user typed in and pushes the message to Firebase

    String input = mInputText.getText().toString();

    if (!input.equals("")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message sent");
        Message chat = new Message(input, mDisplayName);
        mDatabaseReference.child(mRoomID + "_messages").push().setValue(chat);
        mInputText.setText("");

    }

}


private void initRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview" );

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView);
    mAdapter = new ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(this,mMessages,mUsernames,mRoomID,mDatabaseReference);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     initRecyclerView();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mAdapter.cleanup();
}
```

}

And here is my adapter:

```
public class ChatRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "ChatRecyclerViewAdapter";

private ArrayList<String> mMessage = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mAuthor = new ArrayList<>();
private String mRoomID;
private Context mContext;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> mSnapshotList;

private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        mSnapshotList.add(dataSnapshot);
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

public ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mMessage, ArrayList<String> mAuthor, String mRoomID, DatabaseReference reference) {
    this.mMessage = mMessage;
    this.mAuthor = mAuthor;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mRoomID = mRoomID;
    mSnapshotList = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseReference = reference.child(mRoomID+"_messages");
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mListener);


}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_row,parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder called");

    holder.message.setText(mMessage.get(position));
    holder.author.setText(mAuthor.get(position));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessage.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView author;
    TextView message;
    RelativeLayout singleMessageContainer;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatAuthor);
        message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
        singleMessageContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
    }
}

void cleanup() {

    mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mListener);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're inserting the records into ArrayList in `onChildAdded()` and retrieving it in `onBindViewHolder()` of RecyclerView adapter is totally wrong.

Why do you need to create an ArrayList of Firebase Datasnapshots? Use the `Message` class instead (you didn't post Message class structure in your question).

Alter the `ChatRecyclerViewAdapter` like this

```
public class ChatRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // private ArrayList<String> mMessage = new ArrayList<>();  // comment or remove this line
    // private ArrayList<String> mAuthor = new ArrayList<>();  // comment or remove this line
    private String mRoomID;
    private Context mContext;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    // private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> mSnapshotList; // comment or remove this line

    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;  // add this member 

}
```

The constructor

```
public ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mMessage, ArrayList<String> mAuthor, String mRoomID, DatabaseReference reference) {

  // this.mMessage = mMessage;  // comment or remove this line
  // this.mAuthor = mAuthor;   // comment or remove this line
   this.mContext = mContext;
   this.mRoomID = mRoomID;

   messageList = new ArrayList<>();  // initialize messageList object

   mDatabaseReference = reference.child(mRoomID+"_messages");
   mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mListener);

}
```

And inside `onChildAdded()` method.

```
 @Override
 public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    // convert Datasnapshot into a Message object

    Message mes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

    // add it to an ArrayList of Message

    messageList.add(mes);  // notice the changes
    notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
```

Inside `onBindViewHolder()` method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   // get single Message object from ArrayList
   Message mes = messageList.get(position);  // notice the difference 

   // just assuming that you've getter methods in your Message class 
   // please look into your code
   holder.message.setText(mes.getMessage());
   holder.author.setText(mes.getAuthor());
}
```

In `getCount()` method

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return messageList.size();   // return the size of the ArrayList
}
```

**Note:** The way you implemented Chat using Firebase and RecyclerView is totally wrong. You should use/handle Firebase event listeners in an Activity or Fragment instead of it in an Adapter.

Before going into advanced stuff in Android please learn basic things first. You really need to understand how Firebase and RecyclerView works in first place.

Comment: Noted, and thank you for your response. I suppose I'm having trouble finding the line between basic and advanced after only learning basic Java and a few Android tutorials. If I could trouble you further, where would you recommend I learn about RecyclerViews and Firebase? I find even the documentation hard to understand.

Comment: IMO Firebase's documentation isn't that hard to understand. Very basic tutorials on RecyclerView and Firebase database can be found in [AndroidHive](https://androidhive.info). 1. [RecyclerView](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) 2. [Firebase](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/) If you want to implement chat app, refer [TVAC Studio](https://youtu.be/Cw0SmoroyNg) Youtube channel. But I'd strongly recommend you to learn basic things first. Happy coding :)

Comment: What would you consider to be the basics?

Comment: I'm not discouraging you to learn advanced stuffs quickly. Understand the Android UI components first like setting and getting records, into and from UI components. You made mistakes while using ArrayList, RecyclerView adapter, Firebase event listeners etc. Do not jump into chat app in an initial stage. Once you start feeling that you got enough knowledge in Android start chat app. Refer the links which I had given in my previous comment or if you search like "Android tutorials for beginners" on Google/Youtube you get thousands of results. Go through it. Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, this is useful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code above, `ChatRecyclerViewAdapter`'s `getItemCount()` method returns the size of the messages array (`mMessage.size()`). But, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called after adding an item to the `DataSnapshot` arraylist.

You have to also add the message from the snapshot to the messages array for the list to update when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Also, it is recommended that you avoid calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in general for performance reasons. RecyclerView.Adapter has helper methods such as `notifyItemInserted` or `notifyItemRangeInserted` to notify the adapter about new additions to the list.